# Thunar ctrl-click

Tags: shortcut-keys, thunar

Is it possible to add in Thunar file manager something I think I used to do in Nautilus, that is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-click to open the selected folder in a new tab?
I know you can set middle-click to do that, but I would prefer <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-click.

Thanks